# How to handle/Optimize High memory usage in your Android app

Tags: java, android, ram

I've noticed that my app keeps lagging so I ran Android Profiler and I had the following Results :
[image]

my question is how can I identify what's using up all The Memory, and how can I optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's using all the memory is already there in your screenshot: it's a lot of `byte[]`s, `FinalizerReference`s and bitmaps.

Now you probably want to know which code was responsible for allocating these.

Just click on a class name that's using a lot of memory (e.g. `byte[]` in this case). The Instance View pane opens to the right. Click any instance to see the call stack that led to its allocation. Click a few more instances to get an idea of the biggest offenders.

See also [View memory allocations](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#record-allocations) in the Android Profiler documentation.

Comment: and if I know that byte[] is what's using up a lot of memory how do I fix it , how I get What part of my Code is causing this, And what Are the possible fixes?

Comment: I explained this. You look at the call stack. Possible fixes are... ehm... not allocating that much memory in that part of the code ;)